# Ghost template using LESS, background image for buttons not loading

Tags: html, css, less, ghost-blog

I'm creating a custom Ghost.org template using LESS [in way over my head here]. The design calls for horizontal nav buttons, two of which have icons as well as text as navigation cues.

My code is built out following two examples on codepen.io

The first is to create cleanly floating nav buttons:
http://codepen.io/nandu/pen/fkiJn

The second adds in the icons:
http://codepen.io/Cheesetoast/pen/qACsJ

This seems to be a file PATH problem, but might also be due to running Ghost itself.

Here's what I've got:

```
nav ul li a.ss_logo_button {
.NavFont;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: @color-03;
padding: 1.5em;
text-transform: uppercase;
background: url("file:///C:/Users/mememememe/Desktop/old_ghost/ghost-0.3.3/content/themes/BI-v3/assets/images/SeedSpark-Logo-Sq.png") no-repeat 0px -2px transparent;
}
```

I had previously been using the  tag, but this seems to be down the line the more correct way to do this. Also [should] style more nicely.

So, hopefully a VERY simple solution?

Answer (score 1):

Answer was a combination of "hi I'm on a Mac" + "yes, ghost is 'running' even though it's local" * "gotta have height/width set in em's"

```
nav ul li a.ss_logo_button {
.NavFont;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: @color-03;
padding: 1.5em;
text-transform: uppercase;
background: url('../images/SeedSpark-Logo-Sq.png') no-repeat 1em 1em;
}
```

Nice thing too is that when this goes live, the path doesn't need to change at all.

Thanks to @nrrrdcore @kurafire @timocratic @eatings for jumping up & helping out!

Answer (score 0):

```
 nav ul li a.ss_logo_button {
      .NavFont;
      text-decoration: none;
      background-color: @color-03;
      padding: 1.5em;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      background-image: url("file:///C:/Users/mememememe/Desktop/old_ghost/ghost-0.3.3/content/themes/BI-v3/assets/images/SeedSpark-Logo-Sq.png");
      background-repeat : no-repeat;
      backgground-position:0px 2px;
```

}

try this css it may works for both color and image as background.

Comment: Sorry. Should have mentioned I'm on a Mac. The correct – working – version is below.